# Failed to execute query. Error: Execution Timeout Expired

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

Azure SQL query timeout

It happened days ago and lasted for hours, today it happened again.
Seems the error occurs when I try to execute query like "select * from table" or "select name from table where time<.....", which scans the whole table.

But when I tried it on Visual Studio Query, it retrieves me the result after 12 min
[image]

Comment: What's your SSMS version? Please update to the latest version and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Azure, index and table scans are penalized in performance, so adding a 'useless' WHERE to the query that forces it to perform an index seek on the clustered index helps some time.

Try something like Select count(0) from Table where id > 0.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you have to implement pagination for the huge data retrival. First you have to retrieve 10-20 records and then retrieve 10-20 records accordingly.

SELECT [key_column]  FROM dbo.[some_table] ORDER BY [some_column_or_columns]  OFFSET @PageSize * (@PageNumber - 1) ROWS FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY

Comment: I tried @PageSize=10, @PageNumber=4, still time out : (

Comment: Can you share your SQL Query ?